# Is it possible for Parquet to compress the summary file (_metadata) in the MR job?

Tags: parquet

Right now we are using a mapreduce job to convert data and store the result in the Parquet format.

There is a summary file (_metadata) generated as well. But the problem is that it is too big (over 5G). Is there any way to reduce the size?

Answer (score 1):

Credits to Alex Levenson and Ryan Blue:

Alex Levenson:

You can push the reading of the summary file to the mappers instead of reading it on the submitter node:

ParquetInputFormat.setTaskSideMetaData(conf, true);

(Ryan Blue: This is the default from 1.6.0 forward)

or setting "parquet.task.side.metadata" to true in your configuration. We
had a similar issue, by default the client reads the summary file on the
submitter node which takes a lot of time and memory. This flag fixes the
issue for us by instead reading each individual file's metadata from the
file footer in the mappers (each mapper reads only the metadata it needs).

Another option, which is something we've been talking about in the past, is
to disable creating this metadata file at all, as we've seen creating it
can be expensive too, and if you use the task side metadata approach, it's
never used.

(Ryan Blue: There's an option to suppress the files, which I recommend. Now that file metadata is handled on the tasks, there's not much need for the summary files.)